# XML output in proper format in python

Tags: python, xml, linux

The code is :

```
results = ET.Element("results")
machine = ET.SubElement(results,"machine")
mac = ET.SubElement(machine, "mac")
ip = ET.SubElement(machine,"ip")
name = ET.SubElement(machine,"name")
download = ET.SubElement(machine, "download")
upload = ET.SubElement(machine, "upload")
comments = ET.SubElement(machine, "comments")

for line in lines.split("\n"):
         if 'MAC' in line:
                mac = line.split(":")
                mac.text = str(mac[1].strip())
        if 'IP' in line:
                ip = line.split(":")
                ip.text = str(ip[1].strip())
        if 'NAME' in line:
                name = line.split(":")
                name.text = str(name[1].strip())
        if 'Download' in line:
                down = line.split(":")
                download.text = str(down[1].strip())
        if 'Upload' in line:
                up = line.split(":")
                upload.text = str(up[1].strip())
        if 'Comments' in line:
                user = line.split(":")
                comments.text = str(user[1].strip())

tree = ET.ElementTree(results)
tree.write('machine.xml')
```

The Actual stdout output that need to be converted into xml is

```
MAC             : 00:19:ec;dc;bc
IP              : 192.111.111.111
NAME            : 900, Charles
Download        : 36MB
Upload          : 12MB
comments        : Since total througput is very less, we cannot continue

MAC             : 00:19:ac:bc:cd:
IP              : 192.222.222.222
NAME            : 800, Babbage
Download        : 36MB
Upload          : 24MB
comments        : Since total througput is high, we can continue
```

The Actual format I need to be generating is

```
<results>
   <machine>
     <MAC>00:19:ec;dc;bc</MAC>
     <ip>192.111.111.111</ip>
     <name>900, Charles</name>
     <upload>36MB</upload>
     <download>12MB</download>
     <comments>Since total througput is very less, we cannot continue</comments>
   </machine>
   <machine>
     <MAC>00:19:ac:bc:cd:</MAC>
     <ip>192.222.222.222</ip>
     <name>800, Babbage</name>
     <upload>36MB</upload>
     <download>24MB</download>
     <comments>Since total througput is high, we can continue</comments>
   </machine>
</results>
```

Output I am getting is

```
<results>
   <machine>
     <MAC>00:19:ec;dc;bc</MAC>
     <ip>192.111.111.111</ip>
     <name>900, Charles</name>
     <upload>36MB</upload>
     <download>12MB</download>
     <comments>Since total througput is very less, we cannot continue</comments>
   </machine>
<machine>
     <MAC>00:19:ec;dc;bc</MAC>
     <ip>192.111.111.111</ip>
     <name>900, Charles</name>
     <upload>36MB</upload>
     <download>12MB</download>
     <comments>Since total througput is very less, we cannot continue</comments>
   </machine>
</results>
```

I am using python 2.4(it is old but cannot upgrade currently) . If somebody could suggest what is the mistake it would be great.

Thanks !

Comment: First thing: "comments" != "Comment". Also you are overwriting variables all over the place and `userexp`, `apidname`, `stnip` and `stnmac` don't exist.

Comment: And the actual output you are getting is...?

Comment: @ebarr modified code as per actual code. 
sshashank124: I have updated with output I am getting

Comment: How does this work: `mac = line.split(":")` then  `mac.text = str(mac[1].strip())`. This should give an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

You're only creating your child elements once, and changing their contents each time you run through the loop.

Create the children inside the loop instead, each time you start to read a new machine.  Maybe have a sentinel outside the loop and reset it when you hit a blank line.

Comment: If I put inside the loop it will not give correct result, it prints
<results>
   <machine>
     <MAC>00:19:ec;dc;bc</MAC>
     <ip></ip>
     <name></name>
     <upload></upload>
     <download></download>
     <comments></comments>
   </machine>
<machine>
     <MAC></MAC>
     <ip>192.111.111.111</ip>
     <name></name>
     <upload></upload>
     <download></download>
     <comments></comments>
   </machine>
</results>

Comment: pardon, yes, you need to recreate them for each new _machine_, not each new line.

Answer (score 0):

You are only ever creating one instance of machine, which you are overwriting the contents of. Also the current code you have posted should throw the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

To get around this you can create a new `machine` sub element each time you find a line that starts with "MAC".

```
keys = [
    "IP",
    "NAME",
    "Download",
    "Upload",
    "comments"
]

results = et.Element("results")
machines = []

for line in lines.split("\n":
    sp = line.split(" : ")
    try:
        key = sp[0].strip()
        val = sp[1].strip()
    except IndexError:
        continue

    if key == "MAC":
        machines.append(et.SubElement(results,"machine"))
        elem = et.SubElement(machines[-1],"mac")
        elem.text = val
    elif key in keys:
        elem = et.SubElement(machines[-1],key.lower())
        elem.text = val

tree = et.ElementTree(results)
tree.write("machine.xml")
```

This should give the desired output.